# Is machine.config static?

Tags: windows-7

Assuming that a user never touches machine.config in a computer, would that machine.config ever change by an application/OS? Do applications have write access to machine.config?

Comment: It is stored in a c:\windows subdirectory.  So no, not normally.  Never under-estimate the ability of an installer to mess with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory they could although I know of no application that does this. `Machine.config` is typically configured by a human(oid).